How can I make clickable table rows work with HTMX?
I have a table where each row has a checkbox in it. I've added a simple JQuery function that makes the whole row clickable - when a user clicks anywhere within the row, it toggles the checkbox.
I'd like to be able to use these checkboxes with htmx, but it doesn't seem to work. The HTMX network call seems to fire and function properly when clicking the checkbox itself, but clicking elsewhere in the row doesn't trigger the API call or HTML replacement. Is there a way that I can get HTMX to work when clicking anywhere in the row?
Minimum reproducible example for the issue I'm seeing:

JSFiddle: Table with clickable rows.
JSFiddle: Attempt at using HTMX not working as desired. Note that in the console, an API call is only triggered when clicking the checkbox itself.

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.7.1/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src=" https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/htmx.org@1.9.12/dist/htmx.min.js "></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table class="table table-sm table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th style="width: 30px"></th>
                    <th>Item</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr class="clickable">
                    <td>
                        <input
                            class="form-check-input"
                            type="checkbox"
                            id="item-1"
                            hx-get="/api/test"
                            hx-target="#target"
                        />
                    </td>
                    <td>Widget</td>
                    <td>$10</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="clickable">
                    <td>
                        <input
                            class="form-check-input"
                            type="checkbox"
                            id="item-2"
                            hx-get="/api/test"
                            hx-target="#target"
                        />
                    </td>
                    <td>Big Widget</td>
                    <td>$15</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="clickable">
                    <td>
                        <input
                            class="form-check-input"
                            type="checkbox"
                            id="item-3"
                            hx-get="/api/test"
                            hx-target="#target"
                        />
                    </td>
                    <td>Heavy Widget</td>
                    <td>$12</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <div id="target"></div>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("tr.clickable").on("click", function () {
                    var $checkbox = $(this).find("input:checkbox");
                    $checkbox.prop("checked", !$checkbox.prop("checked"));
                });
                $("tr.clickable > td > input:checkbox").on(
                    "click",
                    function (event) {
                        event.stopPropagation();
                    }
                );
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>


You can move the hx-get and hx-target to the tr element, so that all the child elements in the row will start making the api calls, as HTMX supports inheritance.
And then define a function to check and uncheck the checkbox when clicking on row or checkbox.


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link
            href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            rel="stylesheet"
        />
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.7.1/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src=" https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/htmx.org@1.9.12/dist/htmx.min.js "></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table class="table table-sm table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th style="width: 30px"></th>
                    <th>Item</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr class="clickable" hx-get="/api/test" hx-target="#target">
                    <td>
                        <input
                            class="form-check-input"
                            type="checkbox"
                            id="item-1"
                        />
                    </td>
                    <td>Widget</td>
                    <td>$10</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="clickable" hx-get="/api/test" hx-target="#target">
                    <td>
                        <input
                            class="form-check-input"
                            type="checkbox"
                            id="item-2"
                        />
                    </td>
                    <td>Big Widget</td>
                    <td>$15</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="clickable" hx-get="/api/test" hx-target="#target">
                    <td>
                        <input
                            class="form-check-input"
                            type="checkbox"
                            id="item-3"
                        />
                    </td>
                    <td>Heavy Widget</td>
                    <td>$12</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <div id="target"></div>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("tr.clickable").on("click", function () {
                    var $checkbox = $(this).find("input:checkbox");
                    $checkbox.prop("checked", !$checkbox.prop("checked"));
                });
                $(".form-check-input").on("click", function () {
                    var $checkbox = $(this).find("input:checkbox");
                    $(this).prop("checked", !$(this).prop("checked"));
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>




Other then adding props, you also need to trigger change event on the checkbox.
You can do that by using htmx's trigger API:
$("tr.clickable").on("click", function () {
    var $checkbox = $(this).find("input:checkbox");
    $checkbox.prop("checked", !$checkbox.prop("checked"));

    # add this line
    htmx.trigger('#' + $checkbox[0].id, "change");
});

